# How to access a Style that exists in a UserControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a Style declared within a UserControl. I then placed that UserControl in a Window. How can I access the UserControl's style from the Window's XAML ???

Comment: Seems your design is wrong. If the style shared with different controls put it on element above in tree. On application level or window for instance.

Comment: It is a little weird, hard for me to explain why it's like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources are resolved by going up through the visual tree. This is not a usually way to work with styles.

You can do it by code behind :

```
Style style = (Style)yourUserControl.Resources[YourKeyStyle];
```

Comment: I think this will be the only way for me to do it. I was hoping there'd be a way to do this exact approach in XAML, but I guess not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you give your UserControl a name you can simply use an `ElementName` binding to get access to the `UserControl`'s `Style` property.

```
<Window Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
Style="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=Style}">
    <UserControl Name="myUserControl" >
        <UserControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Control">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
            </Style>
        </UserControl.Style>
    </UserControl>
</Window>
```

If you want to access just an individual setter value from the `UserControl`'s style you can use something like:

```
<Window Background="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Source=Style, Path=Background}">
```

Hope this helps!